# SQL query for fetching attributes of person from different tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have a table in which we have one field called “scope” contains single or multiple attributes separated by pipe delimiter like COUNTRY|JOB_CD |AGE. These attributes are define individually in another table which have mapping with table alias name and one another table which gives you real table name to which these attribute individually belong to using alias in previous table.

I have to create a query after reading scope value which retrieve all person IDs who belong to  criteria means “fetch all user who lives in USA with JOB_CD as 23 and age is 30 ”
As we don’t have all person attributes/properties in one table, how to achieve this efficiently..please help.

```
PERSONID    SCOPE                  COMP_VALUE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1234        COUNTRY|JOB_CD |AGE    USA|23|30


ELEMENT CD  ALIAS
-----------------------------
COUNTRY EA  
JOB_CD  EJ
AGE     EATTR


ALIAS   TABLE_NM
-----------------------------------
EA      EMP_ADDRESS
EJ      EMP_JOB
EATTR   EMP_ATTRIB
```

Above tables have many more columns but I posted few which I require

All below tables have a common field person_id.

```
EMP_ADDRESS Table have below column
-------------------------
PERSON_ID
COUNTRY

EMP_JOB Table have below column
-------------------------
PERSON_ID
JOB_CD


EMP_ATTRIB Table have below column
-------------------------
PERSON_ID
AGE
```

Comment: Please, please -- normalize your table...  Then this becomes a much easier task.

Comment: Currently it is not possible to make these enhancement in this old project :(

Comment: First, how do the second two tables map to your problem?  The question you are asking appears to "merely" require parsing the data in the first table.  Second, you say that all three tables have a common `person_id` field but you don't show a `person_id` column in the second or third tables.

Comment: You haven't read my statement carefully :)   Those two tables have mapping of element with table names where all these element exist and in those table we have PERSON_ID as a fk

Comment: @Dev G: How many values of one attribute one person_id can have?
Can one person_id have 2 or more countries, ages, jobs etc. in tables with attribute values?
Or one person can only have at most 1 value for given attribute ?

Comment: The problem with storage solutions like this is that the sort of people who think they're a good idea are the sort of people who are extremely cavalier about data integrity and validation.  So have checked the cleanliness of the data?  Does every PERSONID have 3 attributes in SCOPE? Are they always the same 3?  Are they always in the same order?  Do they always have matching values in COMP_VALUE?  Are the data types in COMP_VALUE always reliable?

Comment: So what ever i posed above are only columns which required to explain my issue, we can have more attributes also in scope or can be less depending on requirement. Order can be different. I need a efficient way to achieve a query which will read the SCOPE, form a dynamic query which can read each attributes value from there tables and finally fetch that attributes matching person Ids

Comment: Okay, so the technical term for what we have here is something which SO etiquette won't allow me to name, but it rhymes with "blusterpuck".  As I suspected, the person who designed this had scant regard for those who would follow in their wakes, picking up the pieces.  I'm afraid you'll have to forgo the "efficient".  Frankly if you get anything that works at all you should be grateful

Comment: I can understand but I have limitation :( I am not aware what was in mind of original designer but now I can't touch much existing one and have to design around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still haven't made it clear how you want to join the output from this shonky CSV table to whatever other tables you have.  So this solution ignores that part of the problem.  If you need extra guidance you will need to provide more information regarding your requirements.

Hers is one solution.  It uses a pipelined function, which isn't necessarily the most performant option, but like I said, your situation is so messed up, you'll have to take "it works" over "it works fast".

Pipelined function returns a nested table:

```
create or replace type bp_record as object
( element varchar2(30)
  , table_name varchar2(30)
  , value varchar2(30) );
/

create or replace type bp_recs as table of bp_record;
/
```

The pipelined function itself:

```
create or replace function bp_cannon 
  ( p_id in your_table.personid%type)
  return bp_recs pipelined
is
    return_value bp_record := new bp_record (null,null,null);
    lrec your_table%rowtype;
    s_offset pls_integer := 1;
    s_nxt pls_integer; 
    c_offset pls_integer := 1;
    c_nxt pls_integer; 
begin
    select personid, concat(scope, '|'), concat(comp_value, '|') 
    into lrec 
    from your_table
    where personid = p_id;

    loop
        s_nxt := instr(lrec.scope, '|', s_offset);
        if s_nxt = 0 then exit; end if;
        return_value.element := trim(substr(lrec.scope, s_offset, s_nxt-s_offset));

        select tl.table_nm
        into return_value.table_name
        from element_lookup el
            join table_lookup tl 
            on ( tl.alias = el.alias)
        where el.element = return_value.element;

        c_nxt := instr(lrec.comp_value, '|', c_offset);
        return_value.value := trim(substr(lrec.comp_value, c_offset, c_nxt-c_offset));

        pipe row (return_value);

        s_offset := s_nxt + 1;
        c_offset := c_nxt + 1;
    end loop;

    return;
end bp_cannon;
/
```

In action:

```
SQL> select * from table (bp_cannon(1234))
  2  /

ELEMENT                        TABLE_NAME                     VALUE
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
COUNTRY                        EMP_ADDRESS                    USA
JOB_CD                         EMP_JOB                        23
AGE                            EMP_ATTRIB                     30

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks APC for your help, let me have a look and get back to you.